# An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ')' error in IDT

Tags: sql, sql-server

While running the below code, I am getting error that says

> an expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ')'.

```
SELECT
      OVUTCMN.FNCNL_LCTN_UE_DIM_TXT.LNG_CODE,
      OVUTCMN.TNT_DIM.TNT_KEY,
      OVUTCMN.TNT_DIM.TNT_CODE,
      OVUTCMN.DATE_DIM.YY_NBR,
      OVUTCMN.DATE_DIM.QTR_NBR,
      'Q'+ CAST(OVUTCMN.DATE_DIM.QTR_NBR AS VARCHAR(10)) AS QTR_DESC,
      OVUTCMN.DATE_DIM_TXT.MM_NBR,
      OVUTCMN.DATE_DIM_TXT.MM_SHORT_DESC,
      OVUTCMN.FNCNL_LCTN_UE_DIM_TXT.STD_ZONE_CODE,
      OVUTCMN.FNCNL_LCTN_UE_DIM_TXT.STD_ZONE_NAME,
      OVUTCMN.FNCNL_LCTN_UE_DIM_TXT.STD_SUBDVSN_CODE,
      OVUTCMN.FNCNL_LCTN_UE_DIM_TXT.STD_SUBDVSN_NAME,
      OVUTCMN.FNCNL_LCTN_UE_DIM_TXT.STD_UNIT_CODE,
      OVUTCMN.FNCNL_LCTN_UE_DIM_TXT.STD_UNIT_NAME,
      OVUTCMN.FALRE_TYPE_UE_DIM_TXT.FALRE_CTGRY_CODE,
      OVUTCMN.FALRE_TYPE_UE_DIM_TXT.FALRE_CTGRY_DESC,
      OVUTCMN.FALRE_TYPE_UE_DIM_TXT.STD_FALRE_TYPE_DESC,
      OVUTCMN.FALRE_TYPE_UE_DIM_TXT.FR_CODE,
      OVUTOI.OTG_STP_UE_F.INCDT_KEY,
      OVUTOI.OTG_STP_UE_F.SRC_TYPE
    FROM
      OVUTCMN.FALRE_TYPE_UE_DIM_TXT INNER JOIN OVUTCMN.FALRE_TYPE_UE_DIM ON (OVUTCMN.FALRE_TYPE_UE_DIM_TXT.FALRE_TYPE_KEY=OVUTCMN.FALRE_TYPE_UE_DIM.FALRE_TYPE_KEY)
       INNER JOIN OVUTOI.OTG_STP_UE_F ON (OVUTCMN.FALRE_TYPE_UE_DIM.FALRE_TYPE_KEY=OVUTOI.OTG_STP_UE_F.OUTAGE_KEY)
       INNER JOIN OVUTCMN.TNT_DIM ON (OVUTOI.OTG_STP_UE_F.TNT_KEY=OVUTCMN.TNT_DIM.TNT_KEY)
       INNER JOIN OVUTCMN.FNCNL_LCTN_UE_DIM_TXT ON (OVUTCMN.FNCNL_LCTN_UE_DIM_TXT.FNCNL_LCTN_KEY=OVUTOI.OTG_STP_UE_F.FNCNL_LCTN_KEY  AND  OVUTCMN.FNCNL_LCTN_UE_DIM_TXT.LNG_CODE = 'en_US')
       INNER JOIN OVUTCMN.DATE_DIM ON (OVUTCMN.DATE_DIM.DATE_KEY=OVUTOI.OTG_STP_UE_F.PWR_RSTR_START_DATE_KEY)
       INNER JOIN OVUTCMN.DATE_DIM_TXT ON (OVUTCMN.DATE_DIM.DATE_KEY=OVUTCMN.DATE_DIM_TXT.DATE_KEY  AND  OVUTCMN.DATE_DIM_TXT.DATE_KEY)

    WHERE
      (OVUTCMN.FALRE_TYPE_UE_DIM_TXT.LNG_CODE='en_US' AND OVUTCMN.FALRE_TYPE_UE_DIM_TXT.FALRE_CTGRY_CODE<>9 
    AND OVUTCMN.DATE_DIM.YY_NBR BETWEEN DATEPART(YYYY,DATEADD(YYYY,-2,GETDATE())) and DATEPART(YYYY,GETDATE())  )

    GROUP BY 

     OVUTCMN.FNCNL_LCTN_UE_DIM_TXT.LNG_CODE,
      OVUTCMN.TNT_DIM.TNT_KEY,
      OVUTCMN.TNT_DIM.TNT_CODE,
      OVUTCMN.DATE_DIM.YY_NBR,
      OVUTCMN.DATE_DIM.QTR_NBR,
      OVUTCMN.DATE_DIM_TXT.MM_NBR,
      OVUTCMN.DATE_DIM_TXT.MM_SHORT_DESC,
      OVUTCMN.FNCNL_LCTN_UE_DIM_TXT.STD_ZONE_CODE,
      OVUTCMN.FNCNL_LCTN_UE_DIM_TXT.STD_ZONE_NAME,
      OVUTCMN.FNCNL_LCTN_UE_DIM_TXT.STD_SUBDVSN_CODE,
      OVUTCMN.FNCNL_LCTN_UE_DIM_TXT.STD_SUBDVSN_NAME,
      OVUTCMN.FNCNL_LCTN_UE_DIM_TXT.STD_UNIT_CODE,
      OVUTCMN.FNCNL_LCTN_UE_DIM_TXT.STD_UNIT_NAME,
      OVUTCMN.FALRE_TYPE_UE_DIM_TXT.FALRE_CTGRY_CODE,
      OVUTCMN.FALRE_TYPE_UE_DIM_TXT.FALRE_CTGRY_DESC,
      OVUTCMN.FALRE_TYPE_UE_DIM_TXT.STD_FALRE_TYPE_DESC,
      OVUTCMN.FALRE_TYPE_UE_DIM_TXT.FR_CODE,
      OVUTOI.OTG_STP_UE_F.INCDT_KEY,
      OVUTOI.OTG_STP_UE_F.SRC_TYPE

HAVING max(coalesce(B.SRC_PWR_RSTR_DURTN,0))>=0
```

Comment: I've added SQL Server tag based on the syntax of the query and the error message. In your future questions, Please include the relevant rdbms tag as well as the specific version tag.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your last `ON` clause:

```
INNER JOIN OVUTCMN.DATE_DIM_TXT ON 
(
    OVUTCMN.DATE_DIM.DATE_KEY = OVUTCMN.DATE_DIM_TXT.DATE_KEY  
    AND OVUTCMN.DATE_DIM_TXT.DATE_KEY
)
```

Comment: [Glad to help :-)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291325/how-to-show-appreciation-to-a-user-on-stackoverflow/291327#291327)